# Hola, estoy haciendo un menu con switch

Tags: codeblocks, vectores

Debo calcular el tiempo máximo y en que lugar del vector fue, lo hice de esta manera pero no me funciona.

case 7 :

```
        for (x=0; x<5; x++)
        {
            if(paradas[x]>max)
            {
                max=paradas[x];


        printf("\nEl tiempo m%cximo de detenci%cn fue de --> %d minutos en la parada %d\n",160,162,max,x);
            }
        }


        system("pause");
        break;
```

Comment: Por que dices que no te funciona? No es resultado que esperas o que pasa? Explica mejor tu problema

Comment: Para que tu pregunta también sea útil para otros usuarios más adelante, ponle un título descriptivo. Además, para mejorar el formato del código, tienes el botón que indica `{}`, o puedes poner al principio y al final del código tres tildes invertidas (`). Y, como te indicaron anteriormente, muestra el resultado esperado y el obtenido erróneamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui lo que estas haciendo es imprimir esa frase CADA VEZ que el bucle for itera sobre el array.
La variable 'max' al declararla dentro del if SOLO vive dentro de ese bloque if.
Lo que haria seria lo siguiente:

```
max = 0
for (x=0; x<5; x++){
        if(paradas[x]>max){
            max=paradas[x];
        }
}
printf("\nEl tiempo m%cximo de detenci%cn fue de --> %d minutos en la parada %d\n",160,162,max,x);

system("pause");
break;
```

Notesé que no intente resolver su ejercicio de una manera mucho mas elegante ni complicada. Solo me centre en que funcione sin modificarlo siquiera.
La idea es que pueda declarar la variable max fuera del for. Ya que si no es declarada de esta manera, la variable nunca existira fuera del bucle for y ocurriria un error de compilacion.

PD:El titulo no coincide con el problema descripto. Trate de resolver su duda en base a lo que lei luego. Indiqueme si estoy equivocado y necesitaba saber otra cosa.
Saludos

Comment: Si necesitas detalles acerca del programa es mejor dejar un comentario (cuando tengas suficiente reputación), también puedes editar la pregunta para que este mejor :)

Comment: Perdón por redactar mal la pregunta y si no fui clara, recién estoy empezando a programar, te agradezco la respuesta ,me fue util, saludos

Comment: Hola! No pasa nada Daniela! Intente interpretar lo mejor que pude tu inconveniente. Espero que te haya sido util y hayas podido no solo dar solucion a tu problema sino tambien aprender algo sobre como funcionan los "scopes" o en español los entornos en los que viven las variables.

Aca te dejo un texto que te puede ser de utilidad donde esta muy bien detallado el porque del problema que tuviste. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm